# JSON Formatting - mailto - cc address isn't working

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, view-formatting

I'm trying to include a cc address for my item list email link.

I used this:

```
 "href": {
      "operator": "+",
      "operands": [
        "mailto:",
        "test1@gmail.com",
        "?cc=",
        "test2@gmail.com",
        "?subject=",
        "Test Subject",
```

The result is the following:

[image: cc]

For some reason my subject lengthens the cc field. Any idea what goes wrong here?

If I look at the code I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint online or SharePoint 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` instead of `?` before `subject` like:

```
"href": {
      "operator": "+",
      "operands": [
        "mailto:",
        "test1@gmail.com",
        "?cc=",
        "test2@gmail.com",
        "&subject=",
        "Test Subject",
```

Example `mailto` format including CC, BCC, Subject and Body:

```
mailto:test1@gmail.com?cc=test2@gmail.com&bcc=test3@gmail.com&subject=Email Subject Text&body=Message Content
```